# SCP file size greater than 2GB

Tags: perl, shell, ssh, sftp, scp

I need to SCP the batch of files (*.txt) between two servers which size is greater than 2 GB. How can i handle this scenario. It takes more time to scp the file.

I tried like below.

```
if size is less than 2GB then 
    go for zip that file (gzip FILENAME) 
    scp FILENAME user@server:/path/. 
else 
    scp FILENAME user@server:/path/. 
endif
```

Is any other optimum solution to handle this scenario.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shanmugam A.

Comment: take a look at [`rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

Comment: how long does it take to scp a file 2GB ,4GB ?

Comment: side note; better gzip alternative for multiple cores, http://linux.die.net/man/1/pbzip2

Comment: @mpapec Agreed, the script should use pbzip, thus shaving off compression time.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable compression using `-C`, for example:

```
scp -C file remote:
```

Better compression is possible but probably will not worth the effort.

Comment: If he is already compressing it, it makes no sense to enable the -C flag. It would just waste more CPU and nothing would happen.

Comment: Ah sorry, you are right. He only goes for smaller than 2GB files.

Answer (score 0):

You could decrease the encryption used by SCP (http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php).
This will give you some increase in the terms of speed.

As far as I recall SFTP transfers did consume all the cores up on my slower machine, but you could also try launching two or more transfers at once. (Measure, measure, measure. Check the default speed. Lower encryption. Then test this. Also check for bottlenecks. Is it the CPU? The network? (If the latter, there is nothing you can do.)

If you need encryption that much, you could encrypt the completed files with openssl.

**Also as others suggested, check compression.**